# Want to print script tag in flexigrid column

Tags: jquery, ajax, flexigrid

I want to print a url in flexigrid columnn
i.e
   `http://www.test.com?q=zys&y=<script>alert("A")</script>&n=y`

But when I am trying to pass it using ajax its showing error.
If I use  tag then its solve the problem but mass up with formatting and , tag are not capable to solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use &lt; and &gt; instead of < and >. That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks ra001, Yes the same i did, I sorted out the issue by using htmlspecialchars() function.